# Adding extra parameters in SWFUpload

Tags: javascript, swfupload

I'm trying to add an extra post parameter for each file uploaded using `addFileParam`, the [documentation](http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#addFileParam) explains itself quite well but when I try to add anything it prepends the value to the size param, causing it to do something like this

```
SWF DEBUG:   'Filename' => 'image.jpeg',
SWF DEBUG:   'cnid' => 'up5121fcacd30besize=539321',
SWF DEBUG:   'Upload' => 'Submit Query',
```

When what I really need is this:

```
SWF DEBUG:   'Filename' => 'image.jpeg',
SWF DEBUG:   'cnid' => 'up5121fcacd30be',
SWF DEBUG:   'size' => '539321',
SWF DEBUG:   'Upload' => 'Submit Query',
```

My Javascript:

```
function onQueued(obj) {
    swfu.addFileParam(obj.id, 'cnid', 'up5121fcacd30be');
    swfu.startUpload();
}
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? I've tried wrapping the value like `'"'` too and I've also tried semi colons at the end. I'm using the [Yelp version of swfupload](https://github.com/Yelp/SWFUpload) as it seems most up to date.